# SQL: Update a row if a condition on other rows is met, in concurrent situation

Tags: mysql, concurrency, database-administration

I'm working on an application in a concurrent situation where multiple instances of the application concurrently update rows in database.
Each application instance creates an update event in update event table, an update event can have status of either IN_PROGRESS/NEW/CANCELED.
I want to create a query to update an update event if:

- no update event on the same itemId with status = IN_PROGRESS
- no update event on the same itemId with status = NEW and timestamp > current update event time stamp.

Table:

```
UpdateId | itemId | status      | time_stamp
1        | 1      | IN_PROGRESS | 1.1
2        | 1      | NEW         | 1.2
3        | 1      | NEW         | 1.3
4        | 1      | NEW         | 1.4
```

With update 1, 2, 3, 4 as above basically I want 2 to wait until 1 is done, if 3, 4 come then 2 -> canceled. Same for 3.

Something like:

```
Update UPDATE_EVENT SET status = IN_PROGRESS IF {
SELECT count (*) FROM UPDATE_EVENT where status=IN_PROGRESS & itemId=item1 = 0
  && 
 SELECT count (*) FROM UPDATE_EVENT where status=NEW & timestamp > updateId_abc123.timestamp = 0
} WHERE updateId=abc123
```

The updates are not very frequent, also latency is not an issue.
Any ides on how I can build the query and is it thread safe?

Comment: Which database platform? You tagged both MySQL and Oracle.

Comment: It's MySQL with innoDB

Answer (score 1):

The main question is how frequently and what performance requirements do you have over this process. There are a shortcut and a very long way.

The very long way would require you to use an ordered/single thread processor that would receive the requests and queue them. Use a stream processor and other ideas to control these requests. Using a stream processor would scale very well if you have a large number of updates in a show time.

For smaller applications, it is possible to check a concurrency isolation level. Concurrency use some locking mechanism to ensure the first one to start the transaction will finish it and only after that other instance would be able to do their changes too.

Both are not quick solutions and would require you to read a bit about them. How to set the isolation level on your SGBD, in the application code, etc.